# Django - Reference to model with 2 attributes

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Currently i'm starting with a user management app.

The case is that we have models `User` (the default django user model) and an `UserMail`.
The `UserMail` has an `OneToOneField` to `User` with reference to the field `username`.

```
mail_username= models.OneToOneField(
    User,
    to_field='username',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Because we also use the database of `UserMail` for another app, I want the password to be in the same table, which would look like this:

```
mail_password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

But the `mail_password` has to be the password from the corresponding `User.username`. So if we choose an user from the `User` model, the password of that user should also be filled in the `mail_password` field

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean under "mail_password has to be the password from the corresponding User.username". Please, clarify the question or add some example

Comment: Your `mail_username` does *not* contain a `username`, it is a reference to the `User` object. So rename `mail_username` to `user`, and query it with `self.user.some_attr`. Note that password in Django is *not* stored as raw text, but hashed.

Comment: I'm aware that the `mail_username` contains the reference, but because it refers to the `username`, the other app works fine with it. What would be the correct way to query it as you mentioned?